# How to import pandas as pd after Installing pandas with Miniconda

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, miniconda

```
bash Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh #installed miniconda on Mac   

conda create -n name_of_my_env python=3.6 #created an environment with python 3.6 

source activate name_of_my_env# activate enviroment

conda install pandas #install pandas by condan
```

Open idle at python and try to create a Series by passing a list of values,letting pandas create adefault integer index:

```
       import pandas as pd  
       import numpy as np  
       import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
       s = pd.Series([1,3,5,np.nan,6,8])  print (s)

       Below is error message:
       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Comment: Can find the directory where pandas is installed on your system? Can you then check your `sys.path` at the Python prompt, to see whether it includes that directory?

Comment: You need to activate that environment first using this `source activate your_env_name` in the command line . Then it should work

Comment: I typed sys.path at Python prompt, and the message showed" NameError: name 'sys' is not defined".

Comment: I did use source activate your_env_name, but still not working.

Comment: Flagged as should be closed because it's unclear.  No question has been asked; obviously the OP wants help fixing pandas, but it's not clear what they have done.  The OP has a pattern of just posting parts of class problems and error messages and hoping that stackoverflow will make things better.  Answers are a mess.  Not sure if close or VLQ is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do a

```
conda install ipython
```

after you've installed pandas? After that, enter ipython and execute your code to see how it goes.

If you are using idle, try:

```
conda install idle
```

And then open idel to run your code.

Comment: I created an environment called dog, and open python idle to import the pandas as pd. I'm not sure how they are connected to each other. I installed" cando install python" on terminals and re run the code, but still not working.

Comment: Can you do a 'conda install idle' instead? The problem might be idle is not installed in your new env so the idel IDE you saw may come from a different environment which don't have pandas installed.

Comment: @Charlotte you need to activate your environment and then install packages. If you don't, they will be installed to the root environment.

Comment: @Allen, I do " conda install jupyter notebook" and open "jupyter notebook". and then run my code there. it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

bash Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh #installed miniconda on Mac

conda create -n dog python=3.6 #created an environment/name dog

source activate dog# activate dog enviroment

conda install pandas=0.20.2 #install pandas(0.20.2 version) by condan

**conda install matplotlib #install matplotlib by condan**

**conda install jupyter notebook**

**jupter notebook**  #copy/paste the URL into your browser to open jupyter notebook

```
   import pandas as pd  
   import numpy as np  
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   
   s = pd.Series([1,3,5,np.nan,6,8])  
   print (s)

   0    1.0
   1    3.0
   2    5.0
   3    NaN 
   4    6.0
   5    8.0
   dtype: float64
```

Answer (score -1):

your idle and pandas are most likely installed at different virtual environments.

activate your virtual env

```
source activate name_of_my_env
```

Install idle/ipython or jupyter notebooks

start idle/notebook from within the virtual env.

now check if you are able to import pandas